# Redirection with "redirect?url' affect SEO? Please help

Tags: seo, redirects, backlinks, dofollow

I'm trying to collect backlinks from an authority site. 
Their systems(text editor) only creates links with these tag

```
<a href="http://authoritysite.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com" target="_blank">
```

When user clicks on the link he gets redirected to the autohirty site, then to my site.

Do these links affect SEO? are these the same as the direct links to my site? are these the backlinks I want to improve my trustrank?
Thank you

Comment: I would not count this as a back link for your site. It is technically possible that it could add value, however, I would even consider adding such a link. I would just move on. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not enough information in your question to say whether they will influence your SEO or not. But my guess is "probably not".

If these are regular 3xx redirects then yes, they will pass rank.

However, if the redirect URL/script is blocked with `robots.txt` or robots meta tag etc. (as is often the case with such redirect scripts) then "no", the links will not be crawled and no rank will be passed. This would make the link essentially a "nofollow" link, similar to when `rel="nofollow"` is used directly on the anchor.

> Their systems(text editor) only creates links with ...

If this site allows any users to sign up and write arbitrary content then any links should be "nofollow" - in the interests of the site (and everyone really). The links are "untrusted".

Only if the user posting the content has been a member for a while and shown to be trusted *might* the site allow links posted by that user to be "dofollow". But stress "might".

Comment: only members can post and create links and membership is expensive, that's why I'm asking. I think your answer is correct but I will contact the site administrators too - to make sure. Thank you very much for clear explanation.

Comment: Even if users are trusted the site admins might still want to control outbound links - limit the number of potentially off-topic "dofollow" links and perhaps allow links to be validated. Then again, the site may just be using this style of linking so they can be easily _tracked_.